# How to create Sublime Text 3 build system which reads shebang

Tags: sublimetext3, shebang, build-system

How can I create a build system in Sublime Text 3 where `"cmd"` is replaced with a shebang if it exists?

More specifically, is there a way to alter the Python build system to use the version of Python specified in the shebang, and use a default if no shebang is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime build systems have an option named `target` which specifies a `WindowCommand` that is to be invoked to perform the build. By default this is the internal `exec` command. You can create your own command that would examine the file for a shebang and use that interpreter or some default otherwise.

For example (caveat: I'm not super proficient in Python so this is probably quite ugly):

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class ShebangerCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def parseShebang (self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as handle:
            shebang = handle.readline ().strip ().split (' ', 1)[0]
        if shebang.startswith ("#!"):
            return shebang[2:]
        return None

    def createExecDict(self, sourceDict):
        current_file = self.window.active_view ().file_name()
        args = dict (sourceDict)

        interpreter = args.pop ("interpreter_default", "python")
        exec_args = args.pop ("interpreter_args", ["-u"])
        shebang = self.parseShebang (current_file)

        args["shell_cmd"] = "{} {} \"{}\"".format (shebang or interpreter,
                                                   " ".join (exec_args),
                                                   current_file)

        return args

    def run(self, **kwargs):
        self.window.run_command ("exec", self.createExecDict (kwargs))
```

You would save this in `Packages/User` as a python file (e.g. `shebanger.py`).

This creates a new command named `shebanger` that collects the arguments it's been given, examines the file in the currently active view of the window the build is triggered in to see if the first line is a shebang, and then synthesizes the arguments needed for the `exec` command and runs it.

Since the default python build system assumes it is building the current file and passing `-u` as an argument, that's what this command replicates as well. Note however that this code is not 100% correct because any arguments in the shebang line will be ignored, but you get the general idea.

In use, you would modify the default `Python.sublime-build` file to look like this:

```
{
    // WindowCommand to execute for this build
    "target": "shebanger",

    // Use this when there is no shebang
    "interpreter_default": "python",

    // Args to pass to the interpreter
    "interpreter_args": ["-u"],

    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",

    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Syntax Check",
            "interpreter_args": ["-m py_compile"],
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice that in the variant we override what the interpreter arguments are; you could also override the default interpreter there as well if desired.

Comment: This looks quite promising—I'll let you know how it goes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If think the only way to do this using a standard `.sublime-build` file is to pass your file to another script which then parses the shebang and passes it on to the correct Python version.

Alternatively, you could specify [build variants](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html#meta-options-in-build-systems), but then you will have to choose the desired build variant manually.

Answer (score 0):

My python.sublime-build

```
{
    "cmd": ["py", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell":true
}
```

In windows I used py launcher to detect the versions according to the shebang