# Sublime text 3: Set different build system for different files

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I've installed Python 2 and 3 and created two separate build environments for both.

I have two files in a folder `python2.py` and `python3.py`. I open both files in Sublime Text 3 and I want the first file to run in the Python 2 build environment and the other file in Python 3.

However, changing the build environment for one files changes it for the other file as well.

How can I fix this so both files are executed by their respective interpreters?

Comment: @YashKumarAtri not really, he only explains how to create 2 build systems

Comment: is problem with indent ?

Comment: You may want to check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768673/let-sublime-choose-among-two-similar-build-systems) for an example of picking a different python interpreter based on a different file.